# How is the temperature of other planets measured?

Tags: temperature, astronomy

I read that it was measured with the light's frequency, is that true? But how do they know it, I mean there's a lot of elements that burns in different colors!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quite a good approximation (how good depends on many factors!) objects which are at some temperature $T$ radiate a *black body spectrum*.  For such a body the power per unit area, $B$ can be described as a function of frequency $\nu$ & temperature $T$ by:

$$B(\nu, T) = \frac{2 h \nu^3}{c^2} \frac{1}{e^{\frac{h\nu}{kT}} -1}$$

Understanding why this spectrum is what it is, and why real bodies approximate it so well is one of the great achievements of early 20th-century physics and is a large subject: the [Wikipeda article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) seems to have reasonable references.

Real bodies such as planets, stars and so on approximate black bodies reasonably well.  So if you can measure the power radiated by a planet, then you can fit it to a black body spectrum, and estimate its temperature.

For planets there is a very important caveat: Earth, for instance, is well known blue, which is (for a theorist like me) approximately white, and you can quite easily match something which appears to be blue or white to its black body spectrum and you will get a temperature of $\approx 6000\,\mathrm{K}$.  Well, the Earth is not at this temperature, or anywhere near it.  But that's light coming from the Earth has two different origins:

- there is light which is reflected from the sunlight which falls on the planet, which has approximately the spectrum of the Sun;
- and there is light which it radiates because it is not at zero temperature, which is what you care about.

To measure the second spectrum you need to subtract the first.  Fortunately it is easy to measure the first, because there is a convenient nearby star with exactly the spectrum you want (this is true for exoplanets as well: you just measure the spectrum of their star!).  The details of doing this are obviously not simple: almost everything astronomers do is heroic, and measuring the temperature of exoplanets is very much so.

Answer (score 0):

All things that are above absolute zero emit infrared light.the frequency of this changes with respect to heat, (higher heat = more energy = shorter wavelength). You can measure the frequency and estimate the temperature by the wavelength emitted. It is only an estimate as other factors such as atmosphere can also affect it.